# What is the effect of the DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK when calling DrawText?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gdi, win32gui

The MSDN documentation for `DrawText` isn't particularly clear regarding the `DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK` flag.

Does it still allow `DT_WORDBREAK` to work with non CJK languages? How does it break CJK languages? If I understand correctly, those languages don't use whitespace like English for example. Does `DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK` have special rules to recognize CJK words or will it break in the middle of a Katakana word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs say what it does, though it uses old terminology. "Prevents a line break at a DBCS (double-wide character string), so that the line-breaking rule is equivalent to SBCS strings." DBCS is old terminology carried over from the code page days. You can think of it as meaning "full width characters". Examples of full width characters are CJK unified ideographs, hiragana, katakana, and Hangul characters.

By default, full-width characters are considered valid word break points. Use `DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK` to disable this behavior.

In other words:

- `DT_WORDBREAK` not set: No word breaking occurs.
- `DT_WORDBREAK` is set, but `DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK` is not set: Word breaks are made at whitespace and at full-width characters.
- `DT_WORDBREAK` and `DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK` both set: Word breaks are made only at whitespace.

The code does not do any linguistic analysis to recognize where katakana words begin and end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, typically CJK text doesn't use whitespace, does this mean, for example, Japanese text will never break with DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK specified? What is the recommended method for breaking space-less text?

Comment: If you use `DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK` on Japanese or Chinese text, it will never break (since Japanese and Chinese text do not use spaces to separate words). Therefore, using it for Japanese or Chinese text is probably not a great idea. The use case described in the documentation is Korean, which does use spaces to separate words. For Japanese and Chinese text, `DT_WORDBREAK` without `DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK` will permit a break after every character.